# What natural integers satisfy the relation $\frac{3}{7}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I would like to find all natural triplets $(a, b, c)$ that satisfy the  relation
$\frac{3}{7}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\,.$

Comment: What have you tried?  One triple should be fairly obvious...note, then, that with $a≤b≤c$ we must have $a≤7$ so just going case by case shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: Have a look at this site, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700130/parametric-solution-of-the-diophantine-equation-frac3n-sum-frac1a). Also search for "Egyptian Fractions".

Comment: Yes I know (7,7,7) works including (7,4,28) but I don't know how to go about it. I mean providing a more appropriate proof.

Comment: @Vector enclose your last comment in your question. This may protect it from closing.

Answer (score 2):

Wlog let $a\leq b\leq c$ then $\frac{1}{a}\geq \frac{1}{b}\geq\frac{1}{c}$

Hence

$$\frac{3}{7}=\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c} \leq \frac{3}{a}$$

$$a\leq 7$$

$a=1$  NA

$a=2$  NA

$a=3$
$$\frac{2}{21}=\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\leq\frac{2}{b}$$

$b\leq 21$

$b=11, c=231$

$b=12, c=84$

$b=14, c=42$

$b=15, c=35$

$b=21, c=21$

I hope you can find other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions are the following
$$
\begin{array}{rrr}
 3 & 11 & 231\\
 3 & 12 & 84 \\
 3 & 14 & 42 \\
 3 & 15 & 35 \\
 3 & 21 & 21 \\
 4 & 6 & 84 \\
 4 & 7 & 28 \\
 5 & 5 & 35 \\
 7 & 7 & 7 \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: You missed (3,11,231).

Answer (score 0):

WLOG assume $a \ge b \ge c$ then $3 \le a \le 7$.

$\frac 1b + \frac 1c=\frac{2}{21}, \frac{5}{28}, \frac{8}{35}, \frac{11}{42}, \frac{2}{7}$.

Now $\frac 1b + \frac 1c = \frac mn \iff (mb-n)(mc-n)=n^2$

Can you take it from here?